# Typescript throws no error when calling nullable function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code in my react app:

[image]

As you can see `onCheck` can be `undefined`. but typescript shows no error and I'm getting a runtime error.

I have to add this prop has no default value.

My tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES5",
            "ScriptHost",
            "ES2015",
            "ES2018.Promise"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `compilerOptions`, add [`"strict": true` in your `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict).

From the docs:

> The strict flag enables a wide range of type checking behavior that results in stronger guarantees of program correctness. Turning this on is equivalent to enabling all of the strict mode family options, which are outlined below.
>
> - `alwaysStrict`
> - `strictNullChecks`
> - `strictBindCallApply`
> - `strictFunctionTypes`
> - `strictPropertyInitialization`
> - `noImplicitAny`
> - `noImplicitThis`

If you only care about the nullable variables, then just use the [`"strictNullChecks"` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the according compiler option set in your [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)

Either add

```
"strictNullChecks": true
```

to just enable the `null` checks, or (recommended) add

```
"strict": true
```

to add a wide range of checks.

Be aware that using `"strict": true` may break your build when you upgrade the typescript version. Because new `strict...` flags will be switched on with that flag automatically.